# Android / Ionic - Video player plugin crashing app

Tags: java, android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

im trying to play a video in ionic app. The code is quite generic and I copied it from the ionic docs. But the app is crashing as soon as I try to play the video.

```
import { VideoPlayer } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/video-player/ngx';

constructor(private videoPlayer: VideoPlayer) { }

...

// Playing a video.
this.videoPlayer.play('file:///android_asset/www/movie.mp4').then(() => {
 console.log('video completed');
}).catch(err => {
 console.log(err);
});
```

Yes, properly installed, configured, imported and provided in providers. So no problem there.

I traced out that this exact section (the part in if ) is causing the Null pointer exception and crashing the app (in videoplayer.java)

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
           dialog.getWindow().getInsetsController().hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
          
        } else {
            dialog.getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
        
        }
```

Thankful for any help.

Comment: I think error will come from plugin.

Comment: yes, obviously, the java code is from the plugin

Comment: Then if the error is from plugin, then only plugin will update then you can solve it.